# What is the point of having a witness sign something?

Tags: contract-law, witnesses

On some documents they require a witness to sign. What is the point of this? Just added security that it's less likely 2 people would lie?

Comment: *Just added security that it's less likely 2 people would lie?* That is the point of any evidence, including witnesses.

Comment: This is a little unclear...are you saying the 2 signatures are to allow things to continue forward if one dies?

Comment: @PatW. no, just a witness

Answer (score 2):

Generally a witness only witnesses the fact that X signed the document; they do not witness the content.

The primary purpose is to make it very hard for X to argue that they didn't sign. However, some documents (affidavits, statutory declarations, certain types of contracts etc) are required to be witnessed to be valid.